# how to recognize many RCTRootViews from one RCTBridge

Tags: ios, react-native

I have many RCTRootViews In many UIViewControllers.They share the same RCTBridge.

I check the source code and find that RCTUIManager store all the RCTRootViews with Key "ReactTag"

One of those RCTRootViews has a TouchableHighlight Component. It's onPress() call a CustomNativeModule through the RCTBridge.

when the RCTBridge recieve the call from TouchableHighlight's js code. I can't find which RCTRootView it belongs to.

I think may be i can get the "root ReactTag",so I can find the right RCTRootView from RCTUIManager.

But I don't know how to get the "root ReactTag" in TouchableHighlight's onPress() function.

I'm not good at js, I check the js source code and find a strange way 

      `var root = this.children._owner._rootNodeID;
      var nativeTopRootID = ReactNativeTagHandles.getNativeTopRootIDFromNodeID(root);
      var reactTag = ReactNativeTagHandles.rootNodeIDToTag[nativeTopRootID];`

it seems just like what i wanted, with that 'reactTag' I can get the right RCTRootView from the RCTUIManager.

But , it feels so strange in that way.

Is there a better way  to recongnize one RCTRootView from many RCTRootViews when they sharing the same RCTBridge?

Answer (score 0):

ok i found write onPress(event)  in js.
use the event argument .

```
var marker = event.dispatchMarker;
var rootID = ReactNativeTagHandles.getNativeTopRootIDFromNodeID(marker);
var rootTag = ReactNativeTagHandles.rootNodeIDToTag[rootID];
```

I think it's better than use .children._owner._rootNodeID